# I have this ajax form code that has failed to work

Tags: html, forms, ajaxform

The form part works fine alone, but on adding the ajax everything fails to function, browser simply refreshes.

```
<form id="myform">

<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="5" />
<input type="text" name="to" />
<button type="submit">Go</button>

</form>

<script>
    const myForm = document.getElementById("myForm");

    myForm.addEventListener("submit",(e) = >{
       e.preventDefault();
    
       const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    
       request.open("post", "https://faucetpay.io/api/v1/send");
    
       request.onload = function (){
           console.log(request.responseText);
       }
    
       request.send(new Formdata(myForm));
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I have eliminated the Api key from the form for security reasons, but in the actual form it is there

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/?more_on=xron.net). See How to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It also very helpful to show in your Question an expected result, and quote any (exact) errors you are getting. You are expected to show any research you have put into solving this question yourself.